# Use ASP.NET forms authentication from Java

Tags: java, asp.net, forms-authentication

We currently have a simple portal kind of functionality built based on ASP.NET Forms-based authentication. All the existing apps that make use of this authentication mechanism are ASP.NET based (and run on the same domain). So, all works fine. We have a new requirement to get some new Java-based web applications make use of the same authentication as well. All our apps are accessible over HTTPS.

Can someone advise here please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We opted to use the *ASP.NET Application Services* for a proof of concept and the output looks promising.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand the specifics of your question, however in general I would guess that Java has the equivalent of Forms/cookie based authentication mechanism in its' web layer, you could then point that API to the same data source as the one your Forms Authentication uses today.

Comment: Hiya.. thanks for that. I did some more research and have decided to give the `ASP.NET Application Services` a try. Hope I get it to work.